# CFStringFindAndReplace instead of stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString for performance

Tags: objective-c, replace

I have a method that gets called hundreds of times and replaces text representations of emoji and replaces with actual unicode:

```
+(NSString *)markupToEmoji:(NSString *)string {

    string = [string stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"[:)]" withString:@"\U0001F603"];
    string = [string stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@":)" withString:@"\U0001F603"];
    string = [string stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"[;)]" withString:@"\U0001F609"];
    string = [string stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@";)" withString:@"\U0001F609"];
    string = [string stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"[:(]" withString:@"\U0001F61F"];
    string = [string stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@":(" withString:@"\U0001F61F"];
    string = [string stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"[:P]" withString:@"\U0001F61C"];
    string = [string stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"[:D]" withString:@"\U0001F604"];
    string = [string stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"[:O]" withString:@"\U0001F628"];
    string = [string stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"[:I]" withString:@"\U0001F633"];

    return string;

}
```

This method has proved to be very slow, with `Instruments` flagging it as the method that is slowing my app down.

I am looking into using `C` and the method `CFStringFindAndReplace` instead as I assume this would be faster, but Stackoverflow only has two posts mentioning it.

Here is the final working version:

```
+ (NSString *)markupToEmoji:(NSString *)string {

    NSMutableString *mutable = string.mutableCopy;
    CFMutableStringRef bufferRef = (CFMutableStringRef)CFBridgingRetain(mutable);
    CFStringFindAndReplace(bufferRef, CFSTR("[:)]"), CFSTR("\U0001F603"), CFRangeMake(0, CFStringGetLength(bufferRef)), 0);
    CFStringFindAndReplace(bufferRef, CFSTR(":)"), CFSTR("\U0001F603"), CFRangeMake(0, CFStringGetLength(bufferRef)), 0);
    CFStringFindAndReplace(bufferRef, CFSTR("[;)]"), CFSTR("\U0001F609"), CFRangeMake(0, CFStringGetLength(bufferRef)), 0);
    CFStringFindAndReplace(bufferRef, CFSTR(";)"), CFSTR("\U0001F609"), CFRangeMake(0, CFStringGetLength(bufferRef)), 0);
    CFStringFindAndReplace(bufferRef, CFSTR("[:(]"), CFSTR("\U0001F61F"), CFRangeMake(0, CFStringGetLength(bufferRef)), 0);
    CFStringFindAndReplace(bufferRef, CFSTR(":("), CFSTR("\U0001F61F"), CFRangeMake(0, CFStringGetLength(bufferRef)), 0);
    CFStringFindAndReplace(bufferRef, CFSTR("[:P]"), CFSTR("\U0001F61C"), CFRangeMake(0, CFStringGetLength(bufferRef)), 0);
    CFStringFindAndReplace(bufferRef, CFSTR("[:D]"), CFSTR("\U0001F604"), CFRangeMake(0, CFStringGetLength(bufferRef)), 0);
    CFStringFindAndReplace(bufferRef, CFSTR("[:O]"), CFSTR("\U0001F628"), CFRangeMake(0, CFStringGetLength(bufferRef)), 0);
    CFStringFindAndReplace(bufferRef, CFSTR("[:I]"), CFSTR("\U0001F633"), CFRangeMake(0, CFStringGetLength(bufferRef)), 0);
    NSString *updated = (__bridge NSString *)bufferRef;
    CFBridgingRelease(bufferRef);

    return updated;

}
```

Comment: Each of these calls creates a new string instance. Did you try switching to `NSMutableString`/`replaceOccurrencesOfString` and profiling? Also, do you really need to call this hundreds of times (per whatever time unit)?

Comment: It has nothing to do with C, perhaps you need to remove C tag.

Comment: @liliscent The question is about using `CFSTringFindAndReplace`. Isn't this `C`?

Comment: No, that's not C.

Comment: "CF" stands for [Core Foundation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corefoundation?language=objc), and is not related to C.

Comment: Well, it's C API though.

Comment: The `CF` APIs are not always faster than the pure Objective-C ones; I would recommend doing what @Groo suggested to start with — instead of making a new copy of the string over and over again, make a mutable copy and mutate that in-place.

Comment: @ItaiFerber I just tested that any is was barely faster. Not enough to matter.

Comment: @NicHubbard: what's the total time spent in this function, number of calls, and average time per single iteration? Is the input string very large? Are you calling it periodically, too often? If this is something that's being called a 1000 times per second, then I understand why it would get flagged.

Comment: It is unlikely (but not unheard of) that there'll be a significant performance difference.  The overhead of a method call is pretty much nothing in the context of a string operation like that and it is quite likely that the backing implementation of both are actually the same code path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is in this line:

```
CFMutableStringRef bufferRef = (__bridge CFMutableStringRef)string;
```

You are casting `string` to a `CFMutableStringRef`, but since `string` is typed as an `NSString` rather than a `NSMutableString`, it isn't actually necessarily mutable. And if it's not, anything that tries to mutate it will crash. If the source string *is* actually an `NSMutableString`, then this will work, but it's very poor form, since the calling code won't expect the string it passed in to have been mutated by this method, and if the calling code continues to use the string after this, it could lead to some really weird and unpredictable results.

Instead of doing this, make a mutable copy of `string`. You can either do that by casting the result of `[string mutableCopy]` to `CFMutableStringRef`, or by calling `CFStringCreateMutableCopy`. Then you should be able to mutate the string without any issues.

Comment: I just used `NSMutableString *mutable = string.mutableCopy;
    CFMutableStringRef bufferRef = (__bridge CFMutableStringRef)mutable;` but now am getting a `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` error.

Comment: @NicHubbard On which line?

Comment: On returning from `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:`.

Comment: @NicHubbard The problem is that the object is getting prematurely released. ARC is releasing the results of `string.mutableCopy` immediately after that line, which is causing the object to be invalid thereafter. Use `CFBridgingRetain` instead of `(__bridge CFMutableStringRef)` to bridge it, which will prevent ARC from releasing the object. Then, you should solve that issue. (Or just use `CFStringCreateMutableCopy` which will also work well)

Comment: @NicHubbard By the way, you should also remember to use `CFBridgingRelease` when bridging the `CFMutableStringRef` back to an `NSString`, because otherwise you'll have the opposite problem—the object will be over-retained and will leak.

Comment: Ah ok, so not just `CFRelease`?

Comment: I also just updated the question with my final working version. Let me know if it looks correct.

Comment: @NicHubbard You should disassemble Foundation/CoreFoundation and look at the implementation of CFStringFindAndReplace....

Comment: @NicHubbard `CFRelease` would work here too, because you already stored a reference to it in the `NSString *` variable, which is managed by ARC, so it should get an extra retain from that. Mix the order of those two up and you could crash. `CFBridgingRelease` replaces both `CFRelease` and `__bridge` in a way that makes the code simpler and cleaner, and makes it harder to make mistakes, and is therefore a better way to go. It should also perform better. Get rid of `__bridge` entirely, and replace the assignment with: `NSString *updated = CFBridgingRelease(bufferRef);`